# Angular-translate - run function after translation loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a little problem with asynchronous translation. I am using static files and translation is going well.

Now I need to get the height of divs with translation text inside to get the same height of each div in row (changing the div height dynamically). I can do that but the height that I am getting is not after the translation loading. When I fire my function after full load (using button for example) everything is ok.

I cannot find proper event that i should listen to get information that translation is ready and I can do something on the site using jquery.

On the site I am using: 
{{'TRANSLATION_TEXT' | translate}}

Do you have any idea how to do that?